# MySQL Workbench, how to fix "SELECT is not valid at this position for this server version" error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

As the title says, the MySQL Workbench is reporting an error. The error is from the software, not from MySQL, as far as I can tell. However, it's preventing me from bug fixing the code, as it will not work on my website.

Originally I used this query, which works perfectly fine, but is very slow, as it has a select inside the inner join.

```
SELECT * 
FROM modeller AS m 
INNER JOIN 
bilder AS b ON b.ID = (
    SELECT ID FROM bilder AS b2 
    WHERE b2.modellID = m.id 
    ORDER BY filnavn 
    DESC LIMIT 1
) 
order by m.fornavn
```

So I've been looking around for a replacement and ended up with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     SELECT p.*, 
             m.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by m.id order by filnavn desc) rono
     FROM modeller AS m
     INNER JOIN bilder AS B
               on B.modellID= m.ID
     ) x
     WHERE x.rono = 1
```

What this query is supposed to do it to look through a database of 3D models ('modeller') and get the latest picture added to that model in the table 'bilder'. This is a one-to-many connection, bilder has modellID as a column, which corresponds to the ID in modeller.

Instead, I get the error

```
SELECT is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting : '(', WIDTH
```

Any tips hints or suggestions are greatly appreciated, especially something that not only circumvents the Workbench-error, but also improves on my initial query.

Comment: which version of mysql?

Comment: @isaace MySQL 5.7, but the error comes from MySQL Workbench (latest version)

Comment: window functions will only work from mysql 8.0, so `row_number()` won't work.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well I guess I'll just have to use the slower one then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative you could try is:

```
SELECT *
FROM modeller AS m
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT model1ID, MAX(filnavn) AS filnavnMax
   FROM bilder
   GROUP BY model1ID

) AS maxVals
   ON m.id = maxVals.model1ID
INNER JOIN bilder AS b 
   ON maxVals.model1ID = b.model1ID AND maxVals.filnavnMax = b.filnavn
ORDER BY m.fornavn
;
```

However, if filnavn is not unique for a model1ID, you could end up with more results than your original query returned. But if that is the case, your original query could provide inconsistent results (since there is no guarantee the ID returned from the original subquery would be consistent when there is more than one row with the highest filnavn)

Comment: This method took my query from 7.125 seconds to 0.031. I'd say that's an improvement! :D Thank you very much @Uueerdo :-)

Comment: @praxiz I'd credit some of that to the fact that your original query had a correlated subquery (a subquery that references the outer query). Such subqueries are run (internally) repeatedly for each candidate from the outer query. They _can_ be faster under specific circumstances, such as when the outer query's candidates have already been narrowed significantly (minimizing the number of time the subquery is executed) and/or a non-correlated version of the subquery is relatively expensive. (ex: finding the max filnavn values for millions of model1ID when only needed for a few model1ID).